# Explaining volatility with GARCH: one-step or two-step approach?

Tags: regression, variance, garch

I am interested in seeing what could explain the volatility of certain financial series. I know that one can get estimates of conditional variance by running a GARCH model. My question is whether the one-step estimate of conditional variance could be used in a second regression where the square root of variance would be the dependent variable which I would regress on some regressors I am interested in?

Or would it be better just to compare the result of univariate GARCH to multivariate GARCH which includes some other variables that I think can explain the variance?

Comment: The second approach you describe would not be called "multivariate GARCH" but rather "GARCH with exogenous regressors". "Multivariate GARCH" would have several dependent variables rather than additional independent variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches have been used before, so it is a good question which one should be preferred.

In the **two-step approach**, the conditional variance is first defined (and estimated) as being conditional on the information in the variable of interest itself, particularly the past shocks and the past values of conditional variance. In the second step, additional variables are brought in to explain the variation in the conditional variance.

In the **one-step approach**, the conditional variance is defined and estimated as depending on the exogenous regressors in addition to the past shocks and past values of the conditional variance. There, the regressors both explain and actually help define the conditional variance (affect the values of the estimated conditional variance).

These two approaches are fundamentally different in how the conditional variance is *defined*. It is up to you to decide whether you are interested in defining the conditional variance with conditioning only on past shocks and past own values or also on the exogenous variables. The difference between the two should be justified by subject-matter arguments rather than statistical ones.

Note that the two-step approach seems to have the following advantage over the one-step approach: you can assess the goodness of fit of the equation where the fitted conditional variance is being explained by the exogenous regressors. There, you can see how much of the variation these variables explain. But actually you can also run a similar regression in the case of the one-step approach, too. Hence, the advantage is only apparent.

Comment: Thanks for answer, by any chance do you happen to know a paper which employs the two step approach?

Comment: @1muflon1, I do not recall any particular paper, but I think I have seen a few. You should be able to find examples by searching for relevant academic articles. The general idea of first measuring the conditional variance and then trying to explain it is quite popular. The particular idea of using GARCH for estimating conditional variance is perhaps somewhat less popular, especially if variance estimates based on high-frequency data are available. But when high-frequency data is not available, using GARCH to obtain fitted conditional variance is natural enough.

Comment: By high frequency you mean intraday data? I have daily data for other purposes I would consider this high frequency, but I usually see people going for GARCH with daily data. Especially in my case the AR model shows heteroskedasticity in residuals and I also tested for ARCH effects with the Engles test and it was highly significant

Comment: @1muflon1, by high-frequency I mean data that are of higher frequency than the exogenous regressors used to explain the conditional variance. If your regressors are monthly, then daily data will be high frequency. If you regressors are daily, then intra-daily data will be high frequency.

Comment: @1muflon1  If I remeber correctly, something like the two step approach is done in the Spline-GARCH paper by Engle and Rangel https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/21/3/1187/1563802?redirectedFrom=fulltext